# Java in html to detect if admin or not

Tags: java

I have this code running in console mode to detect if the windows session is under Admin or no admin privilege, I want to embed it directly in a web page as applet or something like that.

Can you help me to figure it out for web use?

```
import java.io.*;

public class WindowsUtils {

  private WindowsUtils() {  }

  public static boolean isAdmin() {
    String groups[] =
      (new com.sun.security.auth.module.NTSystem()).getGroupIDs();
    for (String group : groups) {
          if (group.equals("S-1-5-32-544"))
              return true;
    }
    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Current user is admin ? " + WindowsUtils.isAdmin());
  }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to make use of applet only? Or a servlet will do?

Comment: If you are planning to use this for authentication - i would recommend you to NOT do so. This would be way too easy to bypass by a user.

What are you trying to achieve with this applet? I think most users will even have applets disabled by default.

Comment: i would like to use applet

Comment: i will explan more : i m doing a webpage, html and php, with secure access login just at first; and after login with unique password, my php script return for our client, his OS, IP address, and i want to know if had privilege administrator, so with theses pre-requies if he can install our plugin or not.

Comment: Maximum browsers will block running applets. I would suggest you think of something else.

Comment: what do you propose? please

Answer (score -1):

You are using PHP for web. So better option is to go with Javascript rather than applet.

```
function IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup(groupName, OnComplete) {
    var currentContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var currentWeb = currentContext.get_web();

    var currentUser = currentContext.get_web().get_currentUser();
    currentContext.load(currentUser);

    var allGroups = currentWeb.get_siteGroups();
    currentContext.load(allGroups);

    var group = allGroups.getByName(groupName);
    currentContext.load(group);

    var groupUsers = group.get_users();
    currentContext.load(groupUsers);

    currentContext.executeQueryAsync(OnSuccess,OnFailure);

    function OnSuccess(sender, args) {
        var userInGroup = false;
        var groupUserEnumerator = groupUsers.getEnumerator();
        while (groupUserEnumerator.moveNext()) {
            var groupUser = groupUserEnumerator.get_current();
            if (groupUser.get_id() == currentUser.get_id()) {
                userInGroup = true;
                break;
            }
        }  
        OnComplete(userInGroup);
    }

    function OnFailure(sender, args) {
        OnComplete(false);
    }    
}
```

The usage is as below:

```
//Usage
function IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms() 
{
  IsCurrentUserMemberOfGroup("Members", function (isCurrentUserInGroup) {
    if(isCurrentUserInGroup)
    {
        // The current user is in the [Members] group
    }
  });

}
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(IsCurrentUserWithContributePerms, 'SP.js');
```

[Link for SP.js](https://gist.github.com/vgrem/8317710)

Comment: Using JS for access control is a bad idea. Too easy to manipulate. Not to mention that the link/library you have referenced is specific to SharePoint.

Comment: so i have just to past this code on my web page? thats all?

Comment: for me java is the most to be handled

Comment: @BeauGrantham Yes javascript is not secure. Its just an Idea, better that using applets atlease, according to me. Please share if you have better alternative. It would be helpful for the community.

Comment: @NewOnDotNet Yes. You can directly use the above javascript (in most of the cases). Still it might depend on your context. Visit the link which I have shared in my answer for further information.